# How to use @Parcelize now that kotlin-android-extensions is being deprecated?

Tags: android, kotlin, annotations, parcelable

How do I replace `annotation class Parcelize` from `package kotlinx.android.parcel` with `@Parcelize` which is not coming from the `kotlin-android-extensions` plugin?

Answer (score 235, accepted):

This should be the new plugin: https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.parcelize

If using **Plugins DSL** you can use the plugin ID in submodules. Make sure that the latest Kotlin Android plugin is available from the project's classpath.

```
// project build.gradle
plugins {
    ..
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.4.20" apply false
}

// app build.gradle
plugins {
    ..
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}
```

When using kts you can write ->

```
// project build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    ..
    kotlin("android") version "1.4.20" apply false
}

// app build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    ..
    id("kotlin-parcelize")
}
```

--- OR Legacy Plugin Application ---

**Step 1**. Update to latest kotlin version - `1.4.20` and replace

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

with this ->

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'
```

**Step 2**. Remove this code from the android {}

```
androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
```

**Step 3**. Finally, replace old import ->

```
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize
```

with new import

```
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize
```

Comment: Step 2 was missing from other descriptions and fixed my issue, thanks.

Comment: I'm new to android development and have no idea but `kotlinx` doesn't have `parcelize` submodule(?).

Comment: What's the `project build.gradle` part for? Doesn't seem to be necessary

Comment: @FlorianWalther the "kotlin-parcelize" identifier is part of the Kotlin Android Plugin. So you need to have the Kotlin Android Plugin in your classpath. Maybe you have added it with the old classpath syntax? Or you have a single Android module (app Module) and added all plugins only there. Then you don't need to define it in your project build.gradle gradle.

Comment: @G00fY Thank you for the clarification. I have the `kotlin-android` plugin which is added to a new project by default.

Comment: even after removing, apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'  Can still see 
package kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize being able to be used.
So gets confused with import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize

Do I need to remove something else as well ?

Comment: I wrote an article about this to use custom @TypeParceler:

https://medium.com/@chrisathanas/how-to-use-parcels-on-kotlin-multiplatform-mobile-kmm-e29590816624

Answer (score 62):

First you will need to add `kotlin-parcelize` plugin to your module.

```
plugins {
    ..
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}
```

Then change your old import statement from

```
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize
```

to

```
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize
```

Edit (source): https://proandroiddev.com/migrating-the-deprecated-kotlin-android-extensions-compiler-plugin-to-viewbinding-d234c691dec7

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where exactly is this plugins {} code block supposed to go in? in the project level gradle file or app level gradle file?

Comment: found the answer. Its not available in the current kotlin stable version yet - https://medium.com/@drjacky/where-should-we-add-plugins-b85517b8a62f

Comment: @G00fY Both 'kotlin-parcelize' and 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.parcelize' are working for me.

Comment: what about this line :  classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"

Comment: Please add that the `kotlin-parcelize` plugin is separated only after kotlin version 1.4.20 and won't be found below it.

Comment: I am having 2 projects, one is working perfact with what i have, like AndroidStudio 3.4,  in project build (Gradle Version-3.4.1,  ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61') IDE kotlin plugin version is 1.3.61. ONe of the project is throwing error as 
"kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.16."
Can u please suggest any solution. Im been facing from last 2-3 weeks.

Answer (score 14):

With Groovy

`build.gradle` (project level)

```
dependencies {
    // .... project level dependencies
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files

    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.20-RC"
}
```

`build.gradle` (app level)

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}
```

and the data class

```
import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize

@Parcelize
class User(
    val firstName: String, 
    val lastName: String, 
    val age: Int
): Parcelable
```

you can find the latest version here https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.parcelize

Answer (score 6):

1. **kotlin-android-extensions** is deprecated so replace it from **kotlin-parcelize**
2. If there is @Parcelize annotation used for model classes so you have to replace its import from  **kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize** to import **kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize**

Answer (score 3):

Before anything you should bump your dependencies versions.
After that, you should change some imports to dismiss the warning and use the right way.

In my case (using macOS), just press Command + Shift + R

Find this: `import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize`

Replace to: `import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize`

Answer (score 0):

Just update your import

from:  `import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize`

to the: `import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize`